# limit app search to apps only in android 8

Tags: applications, settings, 8.0-oreo, search, 8.1-oreo

I have a google pixel 1 that I recently updated from android 7 to android 8.

In both android 7 and 8 I can drag upwards from the bottom of the home screen to go into a view that shows all apps. At the top of this view there is a search bar.

In android 7 if I entered some text in this search bar it would search my list of installed apps for ones whose names contain the search term. In android 8 it shows me all sorts of noisy web and other search results above the list of matching apps.

For example, if I search for 'ca' it shows me a web result for a film called 'call me by your name' and a contact from my contacts list named 'Carl', and a couple of other web search results. Underneath all this noise is where it shows the apps that start with 'ca': calculator, calendar, camera.

Does anyone know how to configure this search to only search the list of installed apps? I use this search all the time and I find the noise distracting and annoying.

Comment: Doesn't happen by me. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It will only shows installed apps. Also may have an option "search for more apps", on clicking it will open playstore

Comment: Any chance, that is replaced by Google search widget?